# System.IO.Directory.GetFiles() not retrieving any files in C#?

Tags: c#, directory, getfiles

I'm simply trying to retrieve all the files in a certain directory.

```
if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(dir_path)) //this line passes
{
    //The following files array is empty although there's clearly files
    string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir_path);
}
```

Is there a way to copy over all the subdirectories, with all files still in their respective subdirectories when copied over?

Comment: Please expand your question to include what you have tried; show examples of what kind of paths you're trying to access. Also verify that the directory has files in it.

Comment: Do you have files in that directory or in _subdirectories_? IIRC, `GetFiles(string)` only retrieves files in the immediate directory and does not recursively grab files in subdirectories.

Comment: How do I tell? how do I enable higher permission?

Comment: The directory has 2 non-empty subdirectories

Comment: According to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx), I think if the caller has insufficient permissions, it would throw an `UnauthorizedAccessException`.

Comment: What happens if you try [EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383458.aspx) instead? Same result? Have you tried debugging and making _absolutely sure_ that `dir_path` is what you expect it to be? Are you passing an absolute or a relative path?

Answer (score 9):

Based on your comment *"The directory has 2 non-empty subdirectories"*, the [`Directory.GetFiles(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx) overload does not recursively check subdirectories and would not pick up those files.

Instead try using [`Directory.GetFiles(dir_path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx) which will grab files in subdirectories as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run Visual Studio as an administrator. If the code runs successfully, then there may be some access privileges issue on the folder being accessed.

Comment: According to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx), if the caller has insufficient privileges, then an `UnauthorizedAccessException` is thrown rather than returning nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem by trying to use `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles()` and believing that it will return me all the immediate contents of a folder.

However, `Directory.GetFiles()` **only returns FILES**. This means that subfolders will **NOT** be returned, only all the immediate  files of a folder.

If you plan on getting all immediate files and folders of a directory you must use `Directory.GetFileSystemEntries()` instead!